# books on algorithms for beginners in Ruby or Python or C. Not too math heavy

Tags: algorithms, books

I am currently at student at Turing and I would like to learn more about algorithmic design while studying programming. Our school mainly deals more with web software, Ruby, and Rails, but I would like to gain an education in algorithms and data structure while here.

Do you have any books for beginners on algorithms or data structure? I only know Ruby and a little Python. Is there anything that you recommend that isn't the CLRS book... it's a tad over my head right now.

How much mathematics do I need to know? My guess is that I also need a book on discrete mathematics?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: It's a good question. I don't think the stack exchange community really likes books on questions.... but in my opinion (and I am a beginner), I do think it's kind of a disadvantage. They are legitimate questions about learning and I need to crowdsource the question. I think stack overflow may benefit from a compilation of answers... or best posts that can be found in each segment of the site. Top books for beginners on certain topics should certainly be an available, regularly updated, and a ready resource to the community.

Comment: "Do you have any books on X?" is not a suitable question for this site.  It is too broad and too subjective-based.  Additionally, polling questions are not suitable for this site.  See, e.g., http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/303/755, http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/874/755, http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/755, http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20/755, http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/487/755.

Comment: If CLRS is over your head, I'm afraid that CS folks are not those whose recommendation you want. It's one of the most approachable algorithms textbooks I know and switching from pseudocode to some programming language won't make things easier. So I'm not sure there's a book for you. That said, Sedgewick/Wayne write algorithms books in which they use Java (C in older editions).

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look at it. How much math and discrete math is necessary?

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, it doesn't really matter what languages you use to learn an algorithm (it's only the syntax that changes, the logic is the same).

However, if you want a Python specific one check out:

- [Python Algorithms: Mastering Basic Algorithms in the Python Language](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Python-Algorithms-Mastering-Language-Experts/dp/1430232374)

A more generic one is by the O'Reilly series (they make wonderful books!):

- [Algorithms in a Nutshell](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algorithms-Nutshell-OReilly-George-Heineman/dp/059651624X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1414533616&sr=1-1&keywords=ruby+Algorithms)

There are also a number of youtube tutorials, so check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5OD9CKrZEw&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvReUrWr94U-ZMgjYTQ538nT), although it is in Java, it is very good!